# Could DigitalProductId and InstallDate ever change?

Tags: windows, registry

I have a software activation logic which relies on thre parameters:

1. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId
2. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallDate
3. Id of system volume

I'm interested in question: **could these parameters ever change under any conditions except manual modification of registry values (for 1, 2) in single OS installation?**

System volume id, as far as i know, can change only when the volume is formated. 
Both DigitalProductId and InstalLDate also should be constant in single OS as they identify a license (concrete windows installation) and the date the OS was initially installes respectively. So according to this logic they shouldn't ever change.

I want to find any documentation that proves these points. Unfortunately my searching for such a documentation didn't give me enough as all that i've found are articles like this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709644(v=ws.10).aspx which contain inderect information on the topic.

Also i've looked through this great post: http://siginetsoftware.com/forum/showthread.php?596-Investigating-the-Microsoft-Digital-ProductID-(DPID)

It partially proves my points but doesn't give a 100% guarantee

I repeat a question here once again:

Could parameters 1-3 ever change in single Windows installation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My research has shown that independently of windows updates, service packs and other software, these keys remain the same.

Comment: Did you find any other readings to support that statement, besides the two articles you linked in your question? Or did you try it out yourself? Anyway, just the second link in your question was worth my upvote.

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't find any articles on the topic. But near year of experience with our application has demonstrated that DigitalProductId appeared to be constant (over 1000 Windows users). Except one case when this parameter was changing on every reboot. I'm still wondering why, but i assume that it could be because they used a cracked Windows.